# How can I cause sbt to handle keyboard input properly?

Tags: sbt, readline

**BACKGROUND**

When running sbt, I must press a "dead" key after each press of <ENTER>; meaning that pressing <ENTER> appears to do nothing... until I press another key -- any key -- when sbt ignores the follow-up key (i.e., "dead key") but behaves as if <ENTER> had been pressed.

After looking into the issue, I discovered that a system property ("[jline.terminal](https://github.com/jline/jline2/wiki/Terminal-Factory-Configuration)") affects this behavior. This property can be one of {"auto", "unix", "win", "windows", "none", "off", "false", xxx} where xxx refers to a class implementing *jline.Terminal*.

When I set jline.terminal to be one of {"off", "false", "none"}, the problem with "broken <ENTER>" goes away.  However, this mode drops support for the linux Readline library (i.e., up-arrow yields "^[[A" instead of recalling a line from the input history buffer).

So, I have 2 options:

- Use "unix" as my jline.terminal and press <ENTER> +  at the end of each input line; or
- Use "none"|"off"|"false" as my jline.terminal and lose my command history support

*How can I have both:  a working <ENTER> key AND support for the Readline library?*

**ENVIRONMENT**

*OS*:    Ubuntu 17.10
*Java*:  1.8.0_161
*sbt*:   1.1.2

Comment: Until an answer surfaces, I have found a work-around:
1) xmodmap -e "keycode 36 = Linefeed"
2) sbt
3) xmodmap -e "keycode 36 = Return"
Where steps 1 and 3 re-program the ENTER key to generate a Linefeed (before running sbt) and restores the Return.

It appears that (despite using a Unix terminal) the program is awaiting a CR-LF (as in Windows).

Comment: I think you should submit this as an [issue to sbt](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/new)